# Why appendChild in js gives an error on appending a queryselected element?

Tags: javascript

Here is my HTML

```
    <ul id="list">
    
  </ul>
  
  <form id="new-todo-form">
    <label for="todo-input">New Todo</label>
    <input type="text" id="todo-input">
    <button type="submit">Add Todo</button>
  </form>

  <template id="list-item-template">
    <li class="list-item">
      <label class="list-item-label">
        <input type="checkbox" data-list-item-checkbox>
        <span data-list-item-text></span>
      </label>
      <button data-button-delete>Delete</button>
    </li>
  </template>
```

Here Whenever I submit form `li-item` should be appended as a child to `<ul id="list">`
and here's my js code.

```
const todoform = document.getElementById("new-todo-form")
const liItem = document.querySelector(".list-item")
const li = document.querySelector("#list")

todoform.addEventListener("submit",(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    li.appendChild(liItem)
})
```

and this is the error I am getting at the console

> Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
> I think I am lacking some concept can someone explain?

Comment: There is no element with the class `list-item` in the document. The `<li class="list-item">` is inside the internal document fragment of the `<template>`. You have to clone the `content` of the template first before appending it anywhere. See the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

Comment: @csAshish, you have to use the `.content` property and do accordingly  ```const todoform = document.getElementById("new-todo-form")
        const liItem = document.querySelector("#list-item-template").content
        const li = document.querySelector("#list")
        const input = document.querySelector("#todo-input")

        todoform.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            liItem.querySelector("[data-list-item-text]").textContent = input.value
            li.appendChild(liItem.cloneNode(true))
            input.value = ""
        })```